# R apply function on groups of data frame

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I need to run ANOVA on each subject individually.
I have a dataframe consists of data coming from 37 subjects and I don't want to loop 37 times to run ANOVA separately 37 times on each subject.
These are the first 4 rows of my data:

```
        latency subject     trialcode
   1    1385    14233664    neighbour
   2    2493    14233664    neighbour
   3    1429    14233664    neighbour
   4    1884    14233664    neighbour
```

This is my code:

```
 tmp <- with(as.data.frame(data),
        by(data$subject,
           function(x) aov(latency ~ trialcode + Error(trialcode), data=data)))
 sapply(tmp, coef)
```

But I get an error message :

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :
```

unique() applies only to vectors

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I'm not a fan of `by`. See https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/explore/sac2.html for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `by` call is not correct.  If I use `data(npk)`

```
do.call(rbind,by(npk[,-1], npk$block,
      FUN=function(x) coef(aov(yield~N+P+K, data=x))))
```

For your data, it might be

```
do.call(rbind, by(data[,-2], data$subject, 
     FUN=function(x) coef(aov(latency ~ trialcode+ Error(trialcode), x))))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data), subject)[, as.list(coef(aov(latency~trialcode+
           Error(trialcode))),by=subject]
```